# Check the number of digits or their range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I tried to create a table for save Tradeshows and I need to save Year and Month into different columns.

I have a problem with my back-end and front-end developers for check data. I need to check years is 4 number and month between 1-12. **Speed is important to me**.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TradeShows](
    [TradeShowsID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TradeShowsName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [YearAttended] [smallint] NULL,
    [MonthAttended] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TradeShows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TradeShowsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `check` constraints:

```
alter table TradeShows add constraint chk_tradeshows_year
    check (YearAttended >= 2000 and YearAttended < 2100);

alter table TradeShows add constraint chk_tradeshows_month
    check (MonthAttended >= 1 and MonthAttended <= 12);
```

Or, you could get fancy and validate that the two together form a valid date:

```
alter table TradeShows add constraint chk_tradeshows_year_month
    check (try_convert(date, concat('-', YearAttended, MonthAttended, '-01')) is not null);
```

Comment: Thank you, this work correctly. But Speed is important to me, can you trust this speed? Do you think there is another way? For example, I only take information from Back-end with SP. Can I make changes there that are better suited for performance?

Comment: AND which of them constraint  is better than in speed ... Thanks

Comment: @Amirhossein . . . I wouldn't really worry about the speed of any of these constraints, because they are invoked only when `insert`ing and `update`ing -- and so much else is going on in these cases.  That said, the raw integer comparisons are probably faster.